# Make XSLT translation file to recognize ascii characters

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have an XSLT that converts html tables into CSV with the definition below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:for-each select="//tr">
            <xsl:for-each select="td">
                <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the problem I have now is that the tables have its tags written in ascii codes.

Sample input:

```
&lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;th&gt;Order ID&lt;/th&gt;
        &lt;th&gt;Item ID&lt;/th&gt;
        &lt;th&gt;Participant ID&lt;/th&gt;
        &lt;th&gt;Status&lt;/th&gt;
        &lt;th&gt;Shipping Provider&lt;/th&gt;
        &lt;th&gt;Tracking Number&lt;/th&gt;
        &lt;th&gt;Shipped Date&lt;/th&gt;
        &lt;th&gt;Shipping Method&lt;/th&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;
            &lt;td align="center"&gt; Choice_DJ4&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;td align="center"&gt; 4&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;td align="center"&gt; DXM09902&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;td align="center"&gt; Shipped&lt;/td&gt; 
            &lt;td align="center"&gt; USPS&lt;/td&gt; 
            &lt;td align="center"&gt; &lt;/td&gt; 
            &lt;td align="center"&gt; 04/13/2017&lt;/td&gt; 
            &lt;td align="center"&gt; Standard Ground&lt;/td&gt; 
            &lt;/tr&gt;
    &lt;/table&gt;
```

My question is, is there a way to make the xsl file recognize the ascii codes as their intended characters.
UPDATE:
        Here is my java code

```
String data = readFile("config/email.xml");

    System.out.println("Data: \n" + data);
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(data));

    String configFile = "config/email-xslt.xsl";

    File stylesheet = new File(configFile);

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(is);

    StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
            .newTransformer(stylesource);
    Source source = new DOMSource(document);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(sw);

    transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);
    data = sw.toString();
    System.out.println("Output: " + data);
```

Comment: Can you include the input source and the desired output in the question?

Comment: The input source is already in the post

Comment: Your input is not XML and cannot be processed by XSLT.  Try preprocessing it and replacing the escaped characters with their unescaped counterparts. Or perhaps switch to an XSLT 3.0 processor that can serialize the input before processing it as XML.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I went with your advice and everything works good now. I have listed below my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 3.0 you can use [`unparsed-text()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-unparsed-text) to load the text, [`parse-xml-fragment()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml-fragment) to unescape the entities, and [`parse-xml()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml) to parse the XML string.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!--first, load the contents of the document (adjust path to your document) -->
        <xsl:variable name="input" select="unparsed-text('table.txt')" as="item()"/>
        <!--second, unescape the angle bracket entities -->
        <xsl:variable name="table-text" select="parse-xml-fragment($input)" as="item()"/>
        <!--third, parse the serialized XML string -->
        <xsl:variable name="table" select="parse-xml($table-text)" as="item()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$table//tr">
            <!--a more simplified way of generating the CSV for each row -->
            <xsl:value-of select="td" separator=","/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In the first comment, you asked that I adjust the path to my document, but I am doing the transformation from within my code where I pass in a string value. How do I go about that?

Comment: Then omit that step and XPath to the text, sending that to step 2. You said the example was your input, so I thought that was the doc being transformed. Next time provide a more complete example to avoid confusion

Comment: Can you please explain how to go about the xpath thing. I have update the OP with the code snippet I am using.

Comment: What does the config/email.xml look like? It hard to suggest an XPath without knowing the structure of the doc. What is the example escaped markup inside of?

Comment: But you could use the XPath to select the escaped table markup, like this: parse-xml-fragment( /docElement/elementX/text() )

Comment: Config/email.xml is same as the sample output in the OP

Comment: Sorry, I meant the data variable. The input being transformed. What you have shown is not well-formed XML, just text.

Comment: The data variable is the content of the file which is the malformed xml.

Comment: So, you need well-formed XML as the input to your stylesheet. Using my answer as a template, you can send the stylesheet(or any well-formed CML doc) as the "xml document" and the send the location of the data file in a parameter, then load that doc as I unparsed-text.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to finally solve the problem... Uisng `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);`

My xsl file and data input(config/email.xml) still remains as that from the OP but I have to modify the java code to unescape those characters before passing down to the xsl translator.

```
String data = readFile("config/email.xml");
data = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(data);
System.out.println("Data: \n" + data);
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(data));

String configFile = "config/email-xslt.xsl";

File stylesheet = new File(configFile);

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(is);

StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
     .newTransformer(stylesource);
Source source = new DOMSource(document);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(sw);

transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);
data = sw.toString();
System.out.println("Output: " + data);
```